# Using Java classes to upload a file to a server

Tags: java, http, file-upload, inputstream, urlconnection

I want to create a Java application ( and then make it and applet to work on the web) that allows to upload a file to a remote server. The file has already been downloaded previously from the server. I have already have the code for the download part, but for the uploading I have the following code shown below..

The import libraries are fine but the issue is on the **Uploader** class that does throw me an error.. I think my **BufferReader** class is missing something but I need your help to debugging it...

**UploadApplet.java**

```
import com.leo.upload.BufferReader;
import com.leo.upload.Uploader;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.AccessControlException;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.LoggingPermission;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class UploadApplet extends JApplet {


      public void start()
      {
        super.start();
        uploadFile("/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Tesing123.indd","http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/");
      }


     public String uploadFile(String paramString1, String paramString2)
      {
        String str = "0";
        try {
          // I call the Uploader class to make the upload to the server
              str = (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new Uploader(paramString1, paramString2));
          System.out.println(str);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
      }
```

**Uploader.java**

```
import com.leo.upload.BufferReader;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Uploader
  implements PrivilegedAction<String>
{
  private static final String a = Uploader.class.getName();

  private Logger b = Logger.getLogger(a);
  private String c;
  private String d;

  public Uploader(String paramString1, String paramString2)
  {
    this.c = paramString1;
    this.d = paramString2;
  }

  public String run()
  {
    FileInputStream localFileInputStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = null;
    Writer localWriter = null;
    InputStream localInputStream = null;
    LineNumberReader localLineNumberReader = null;

    Object localObject1 = "0";
    try
    {
      File localFile = new File(this.c);
      localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
      localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(localFileInputStream);

      Object localObject2 = new URL(this.d);
      URLConnection localURLConnection = ((URL)localObject2).openConnection();

      localURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Filename", localFile.getName());
      localURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/binary");

      long l = localFile.length();
      Object localObject3;
      if (l <= 2147483647L) {
        if ((localURLConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
          localObject3 = (HttpURLConnection)localURLConnection;
          ((HttpURLConnection)localObject3).setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int)localFile.length());
        }

        localURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        **// I call the BufferReader class, and the a method to perform the writing**
        BufferReader.a(localBufferedInputStream, localURLConnection.getOutputStream());

        localInputStream = localURLConnection.getInputStream();
        localLineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(localInputStream, "UTF8"));
        localObject1 = localLineNumberReader.readLine();
      }
      else {
        localObject3 = "An error occurred during file upload: Cannot upload a file larger than 2GB.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, localObject3, "Error during file upload", 0);
        this.b.severe((String)localObject3);
        localObject1 = localObject3;
      }
    }
    catch (Throwable localIOException4) {
        localIOException4.printStackTrace();

      Object localObject2 = "An error occurred during file upload: " + localIOException4.toString();
      localObject1 = localObject2;
    } finally {
      BufferReader.a(localFileInputStream, localBufferedInputStream, localWriter);
      if (localLineNumberReader != null) {
        try {
          localLineNumberReader.close();
        } catch (IOException localIOException5) {
          localIOException5.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (localInputStream != null) {
        try {
          localInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException localIOException6) {
          localIOException6.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return (String)(String)(String)localObject1;
  }


}
```

**BufferReader.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class BufferReader
{
  private static Logger logthis = Logger.getLogger(BufferReader.class.getName());

  public static void a(InputStream paramInputStream, OutputStream paramOutputStream)
    throws IOException
  {
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[4096];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while ((j = paramInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) != -1) {
      paramOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, j);
      i += j;
    }
    logthis.fine("CopyBytes : " + i);
  }

  public static void a(InputStream paramInputStream, FileOutputStream paramFileOutputStream, BufferedOutputStream paramBufferedOutputStream)
  {
    if (paramInputStream != null) {
      try {
        paramInputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException localIOException1) {
        localIOException1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    if (paramFileOutputStream != null) {
      try {
        paramFileOutputStream.flush();
      } catch (IOException localIOException2) {
        localIOException2.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    if (paramBufferedOutputStream != null) {
      try {
        paramBufferedOutputStream.flush();
      } catch (IOException localIOException3) {
        localIOException3.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    if (paramFileOutputStream != null) {
      try {
        paramFileOutputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException localIOException4) {
        localIOException4.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    if (paramBufferedOutputStream != null)
      try {
        paramBufferedOutputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException localIOException5) {
        localIOException5.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public static void a(InputStream paramInputStream, BufferedInputStream paramBufferedInputStream, Writer paramWriter)
  {
    if (paramBufferedInputStream != null)
      try {
        paramBufferedInputStream.close();
      }
      catch (IOException localIOException1)
      {
      }
    if (paramInputStream != null)
      try {
        paramInputStream.close();
      }
      catch (IOException localIOException2)
      {
      }
    if (paramWriter != null)
      try {
        paramWriter.close();
      }
      catch (IOException localIOException3)
      {
      }
  }

  public static String a(InputStream paramInputStream)
    throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(paramInputStream, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String str = null;

    while ((str = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      localStringBuilder.append(str);
    }

    localBufferedReader.close();
    return localStringBuilder.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Give us the stack trace.

Comment: What's with the one-letter names for methods and variables? If you want to obfuscate your binaries, write normal code and use on obfuscator on the class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that unsigned applets aren't usually allowed to open connections to addresses that aren't their originating web server...unless you specify that applets can do whatever they want in the client's java control panel

Comment: Actually, I want this code to behave correctly and then, convert it into applet. If I fire it from eclipse, it should work fine... Any ideas about what could be hapening on these lines where my code is stuck?

      localInputStream = localURLConnection.getInputStream();
        localLineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(localInputStream, "UTF8"));
        localObject1 = localLineNumberReader.readLine();

Comment: @Leo we can't help you until you show us what the exception trace is!!!...Are you inferring that the code is blocking at that line, or are you receiving an exception?!